# DAO difference between C# and VBA RecordSets

Tags: c#, vba, dao, recordset

In VBA I might have something like this:

```
    Dim recordSet As DAO.recordSet  
    result = recordSet("Column Name")
```

Im trying to do the same thing in C#, However

```
    result = recordSet("Column Name");
```

wouldnt work because C# uses square brackets for collections.
But this doesnt seem to work either:

```
    result = recordSet["Column Name"];
```

Any ideas on the C# equivalent of the above VBA code?

**EDIT:** Here is the full VBA code Im trying to convert to put it into context

```
Public Function GetColumnValues( _
                                 database As database, _
                                 column As String, _
                                 table As String _
                               ) As String()

Dim sqlQuery As String
Dim recordSet As DAO.recordSet
Dim recordCount As Integer
Dim results() As String

sqlQuery = "SELECT [" + table + "].[" + column + "]" & _
           "FROM [" + table + "];"


Set recordSet = database.OpenRecordset(sqlQuery)
recordSet.MoveLast             
recordSet.MoveFirst
recordCount = recordSet.recordCount

ReDim results(recordCount) As String

For i = 1 To recordCount
    results(i) = recordSet(column)
    recordSet.MoveNext
Next i

recordSet.Close

GetColumnValues = results

End Function
```

Comment: You are more likely to receive help if you post the C# code that you have attempted, together with any error messages.

Comment: I am not sure, but please try `recordSet.Fields["Column Name"]`;

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly Thanks! it ended up being recordSet.Fields["Column Name"].Value; Please post as an answer and Ill accept it.

Comment: the `+` is not a valid concatenation operator in VBA. you should have used `&` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = recordSet.Fields["Column Name"].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is a DataSet or DataTable maybe what you are looking for?

Edit:
Try something like this (not tested yet and some error handling is needed):

```
    public string[] GetColumnValues(string connectionString, string table, string column)
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
            string.Format("SELECT [{0}].[{1}] FROM [{0}]", table, column), connection);
        var result = new List<string>();

        connection.Open();

        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            result.AddRange(from DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows select row[0].ToString());
        }

        connection.Close();

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Please see my edit, I added the VBA function that im trying to convert to C# to help put it into context

Comment: What import parameters do you have in your C# code. And what return type do you expect/need?

Comment: Im not to sure what your asking with the Import parameters. Im simply trying to create a C# equivalent of the exact code I posted above. The results variable is expecting a string.

Comment: I appreciate the code snippet, but I have to use the DAO framework. Im looking for the equivalent DAO code from VBA to C#. Which I have done except for the recordSet line I originally asked for.